# Styling paragraphs NOT preceded by a heading level element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I wonder whether it is possible to style a paragraph not preceded by a heading?

I guess the rule would look something like this:

```
  p (direction for "without/not preceded by") h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
```

Or... does the rule have to be written for the opposite:

```
  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 + p {
```

...therefore paragraphs could have the style desired for a paragraph not preceded by a heading, by default.

Kind Regards,
Dale

Comment: What other elements *can* `p` elements follow? If your HTML structure for these paragraphs is restricted enough you can select in an "only these" basis rather than an "anything but these" basis.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure you have to write the opposite, as you described. Two important points, however:

1. The first solution that comes to my mind is using `:not`, or [the negation pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation). However, it only takes a simple selector, so

   ```
   :not(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6) + p
   ```

   would be illegal.
2. As you have written your second selector, the `+ p` term only applies to the `h6`; paste it into the [SelectORacle](http://tux.theopalgroup.com/cgi-bin/css3explainer/selectoracle.py) to see. The correct selector would be

   ```
   h1 + p, h2 + p, h3 + p, h4 + p, h5 + p, h6 + p
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Style all your paragraphs the way you would like them to appear without headings preceding them:

```
p {//styles here}
```

Then, farther down in the stylesheet, add the styles for paragraphs preceded by headers:

```
h1 + p, h2 + p, etc {//styles here}
```

The regular paragraphs will be styled as you want them.  The ones with preceding headers will get the later styles.

EDIT: I should add that the later styles will inherit from the earlier styles, so you will need to overwrite certain rules... for instance, if you have `background-color: red` on all your `p` tags but you do not want a red background on the `p` that are preceded by an `h`, then you need to set that `background-color` to `none` or another color, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions guys.

I felt that there was some selector that would do the job, but it looks very dodgy to use that one.

I will go with:

```
 p {
```

and then, lower in the cascade:

```
 h1 + p, h2 + p, h3 + p, h4 + p, h5 + p, h6 + p {
```

Annoying that the

```
 p {
```

is the exception rather than the rule : D